# Pandas select rows matching variable number of values in many columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to write a function that will select a subset of a `pd.DataFrame`. I want to use multiple selection values for different columns.

For example:

```
column_a matches 'a' or 'b' or ...
column_b matches 'A' or 'B' or 'X' ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by selection?

Comment: use `isin`, e.g. `df.indicator_name.isin(list_of_indicators)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide your values as variable args or a list you can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```py
# Using `*args`
def select_args(df, column, *args):
    return df[df[column].isin(args)]

# Using a list
def select_list(df, column, list_):
    return df[df[column].isin(list_)]
```

Use like so:

```py
>>> df_sub = select_args(df, "indicator", "A", "B", "C")
>>> df_sub = select_list(df, "indicator", ["A", "B", "C"])
```

---

For using multiple columns, with many different variables you should structure these data as pairs. For example, you could use a `dict` where each key is a `column` and the value is a `list`:

```py
search_params = {
    "column_a": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "column_b": ["A", "B", "C"],
}
```

Then you can create your boolean arrays, combine them using `np.all` and subset your DataFrame:

```py
def select_multiple(df, selectors):
    bools = [df[col].isin(vals).to_numpy() for col, vals in selectors.items()]
    return df[np.all(bools, axis=0)]

>>> df_sub = select_multiple(df, search_params)
```

Comment: Thank you!  What would you do if there are multiple columns and each of them have the same issue? Is nested function the only way?

Comment: Do you want to search for the same list in multiple columns or different values in each column?

Comment: I need to search different values in each column. I need to have multiple *args for different columns.

Comment: All at the same time? So only return rows where all values are true?

Comment: Yes. conditions needs to be made for all columns at the same time.

Comment: See my updated answer